# how to autofill textboxes when switching from one tab to another in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing an application (in c# using Visual studio 2012) where i have to read a config file which is in .txt format. I am also using tab control to switch between different tab.
what i want to do is that, when i click on config tab, my application should read the config file and place the data that i require into the text boxes that are present under that tab.
Any help would be appreciated.

i have tried placing the code to autofill my textboxes in the form constructor and it works, but i don't want to do it through constructor because it will only read the config file when the form is created and not when i switch from one tab to another.

Comment: @user2283679 - you want to auto fill the texboxes or not, first tell us correctly your question

Comment: yeah i want to autofill my textbox, but i don't want it to do it through constructor.

Comment: sorry can't show the code...it's an intellectual property of some company....

Comment: @Kratos: There are a lot of ways to do this. Tell us something about the way you want to go and not the way you don't want to take.

Comment: see i want that when i switch from some tab to this particular tab it should read the config file each time and show me the latest content in the textboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the SelectedIndexChanged event of tab control.

```
tabContrl1.TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged += tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Add the event handler. Name your config tab as "ConfigTab" (Or whatever you want).

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

    if (tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name.Equals("ConfigTab")) {

       //Fill textbox here

}

}
```

Comment: where do u want me to place this code: "tabContrl1.TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged += tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged;"

Comment: You can add this in form load. And add the event handler to the same class.
OR
Directly add the event for the tab control you are using. Just make sure you add the event for "TabControl" and not "TabPage"

Comment: i also noted that all the tabs have same tab index so how can i differentiate between the different tabs

Comment: Check for the edit. You need to give a name for your config tab and then use the code.

Comment: @Kratos tab index is the order in which controls are focused when pressing tab key, that's a different thing
but all tabs in the TabControl have unique, zero-based index and that's what you can check

Comment: @Harsh.....your solution is working to some extent. the scenario that's happening is when i m running my program i get my form in which i have a tabcontrol with three tabs. In first tab page there are textboxes. so according to ur solution when i run my program i get empty textboxes but when i switch tabs and come back to the first tab then only they r filled. But what i want is that they should be filled when i first run the program and not when i switch tabs.

Comment: That is a different requirement. You need to add the values in some other event. This solution was for your combobox fillups.

Answer (score 1):

In your `design` view select the entire tabControl.

Then click the events button (lightning bolt) on the properties window.

Then double click `SelectedIndexChanged`

here is a sample code:

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // "First Tab Page" is the text of the tab page.
    if ((sender as TabControl).SelectedTab.Text == "First Tab Page")
    {
        string filecontents = File.ReadAllText(@"path\to\configFile.txt");
        textBox1.Text = filecontents;
    }
}
```

Simple?